# Period of a pendulum in a lift going up

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, lift

So I know that the period of a pendulum in a free falling elevator isn't going to change because there is no force acting on it since $$T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\ell}{g}}.$$
So what happens to a pendulums period when it's going up in a lift in a constant speed, and what will happen to the period of a pendulum if it's accelerating up in a lift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Period of pendulum in falling lift](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/123339/p)

Comment: It's not a duplicate the answer you posted is for a lift falling not going up...

Comment: Well think of it like this, you are going negative down when you go up

Comment: But it isn't free falling

Comment: The reason J Rennie posted that was in the hopes you could actually *learn* something about how to calculate the net force on an object.